# Ajax script to update record does not work, Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I wrote a small script that updates the information on the page when editing. Everything basically works as it should, but I just can’t update the image. I don’t understand what the matter is. Without a script, with a page reload, everything works as it should.

Ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("document").ready(function() {
        $("#editPostButton{{$post->id}}").click(function() {

            var formData = $("#EditPostForm{{$post->id}}").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{route('editPost', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id])}}",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#textpostdata{{$post->id}}").html($(data).find("#textpostdata{{$post->id}}").html());
                    $("#closeButton{{$post->id}}").click();
                }
           });

        });
    });

</script>
```

My Controller

```
public function editPost(Request $request, $id, $postId) {

    $validator  = $this->validate($request,[
        'title' => 'max:100',
        'message' => 'max:5000',
        'img' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,gif,jpg|max:5000',
        'videoPost' => 'max:100'
    ]);

    if($validator) {
        $user = User::find($id);
        if(!$user && $user != Auth::user()->id) {
            return abort(404);
        }
        $post = Profile::find($postId);
        if(!$post) {
            return abort(404);
        }

        $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->message = $request->message;
        $post->videoPost = str_replace('watch?v=', 'embed/', $request->videoPost);

        if($request->file('img')) {
            $path = Storage::putFile('public/'.Auth::user()->id.'/post', $request->file('img'));
            $url = Storage::url($path);
            $post->img = $url;
        }

        $post->update();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

And update form

```
<form action="{{route('editPost', ['id' => $user->id, 'postId' => $post->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="EditPostForm{{$post->id}}" name="postForm">
     @csrf @method('PATCH')
     <div class="form-group">
         <textarea maxlength="100" name="title" class="form-control" rows="1">{{$post->title}}</textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <textarea id="message" maxlength="5000" name="message" class="form-control" rows="10">{{$post->message}}</textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <textarea maxlength="100" class="form-control mt-1" id="videoPost" name="videoPost" cols="100" rows="1">{{$post->videoPost}}</textarea>
     </div>
     <h6>Current image</h6>
     <img src="{{$post->img}}" class="img-fluid mb-2" width="230">
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
     </div>

     <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="editPostButton{{$post->id}}">Edit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: the fact of the matter is that nothing is displayed. I tried to separately update the picture now, fakepath got out